# Soap API integration in Laravel Framework

Tags: soap, laravel-10, laravel-api

I have a Soap API documentation of SSLCommerz. But I do not understand **how can I integrate it into my remaining Laravel project**. There are methode_name, request, and response in the soap API documentation. I can not understand where should I integrate the XML codes. Could You help me plz.